# 16.04.4 kernel not supporting PERC H740p RAID controller even though 17.10 does

Tags: 16.04, kernel, raid, lts

16.04.4 uses the 17.10 kernel. In other posts here it's stated that the Dell PERC H740p RAID controller is supported from Kernel version 4.11/4.13 up. Surely it should therefore work in 16.04.4?

No drive controllers are found during installation.

Is this a bug that I should report?

edit: In fact my fresh install of 16.04.4 server says it's running kernel 4.4.0.116 un name -a even though /etc/lsb-release shows 16.04.4. What's going on here?????

Comment: 16.04.4 is the image that's released.  You would have to upgrade your system kernel to the kernels from 16.04.4, and switch to kernels 4.11/4.13, which is *not* an automatic process/step.

Comment: Tom, so if I require the 4.13 kernel to INSTALL Ubuntu then I have no option but to migrate to 17.10? Is there not a way of installing using the 4.13 kernel so that it will pick up my RAID controller? I'd need to do a huge amount of QA to do a distro update.

Comment: That's not what I said.  give me a minute I'm doing research on this issue.  Patience is a virtue.

Answer (score 3):

> NOTE: This answer does **NOT** say "Install 17.10".  Under no circumstances do I suggest doing that.  This answer contains instructions for how to upgrade the kernel if you are already on 16.04, and tells you what packages you need to install within 16.04 to get the newer kernel.

Every Ubuntu system that is running on 16.04 is now considered in `lsb_release`'s case to be 16.04.4 because all the *other* updates that were done to the disk image were already grabbed during standard Ubuntu updates/upgrades within the OS by update tasks such as `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and others.

With one exception: the kernel does not get upgraded automatically to the backported kernels.  That is only done on fresh installations because that's the kernel that ships on the installer disks. But, because not everything uses the HWE upgraded kernels, there are cases where you can't switch kernels because something *else* is unsupported in the newer kernel, or any other cases where you are dependent on a certain kernel, the system does not automatically upgrade you to the HWE 'updated' kernels.

You have to install `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and its dependent packages on a Xenial box to get to the newer 4.13 kernel that was backported:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

The above command should work for you.  You may need to also run this afterwards to make sure GRUB sees the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once that's done, reboot your computer.  It should boot to the newer Kernel.

(A note: Just because the kernel is backported doesn't *necessarily* mean that your RAID controller is still supported - not everything backports cleanly, despite Kernel team efforts to enable hardware support)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I'm still in the situation where I can't install anything older than 17.10 on this brand new server I've received. Is there any way of installing Xenial on it?

Comment: @user1827139 **I didn't *say* to install 17.10**.  I assumed you were working with Xenial.  Download a new 16.04.4 ISO and burn that to a disk.  Then boot to that disk and install Xenial.  That *should* have the proper kernel version already - 4.13.x.

Comment: As the latest 16.04.4 liveCD uses the 4.4.0 kernel it can't see the RAID array so I can't install.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot. The solution is:
[image]